# Dynamic rule creation in drools with different number of conditions and actions in each rule

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

I am new to Drools. As per my usecase, I want to dynamically create the rules. I have considered using the following rule template:

```
 template header

 rule
 eventType

 package org.ossandme;

 global org.ossandme.AlertDecision alertDecision;

 template "alert"

 rule "alert_@{row.rowNumber}"

 when
      @{eventType}(@{rule})
 then
      alertDecision.setDoAlert(Boolean.TRUE);
 end

 end template
```

But the problem with this template is that it fixes the number of conditions and actions (1 in this case). According to my use case, I might have different number of conditions and actions in different rules. Is it possible to create a generic template which can create rules, with different number of conditions and different number of actions in each rule?

Answer (score 0):

Drools templates is just a fancy name for a String template mechanism. You can use whatever template framework you want to create your rules.

Some of the frameworks I've used in the past are:

- Manual String concatenation using a `StringBuilder`
- [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)
- [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

The other answer suggesting any String template framework is correct; alternatively, if you want a pure Java-based solution, you may want to consider writing your rule dynamically with code using the Executable Model DSL.

You can reference [this blog post](http://blog.athico.com/2018/02/the-drools-executable-model-is-alive.html) which has link to references and examples how to use it.